# jQuery ui Slider value not reading

Tags: jquery-ui-slider

I created value slider with jQuery.

```
<div class="specialSearch">
    <form action="#" method="GET">
        <script type="text/javascript">
             $(function() {
                $( "#juiSlideIMDB" ).slider({
                    value: 7.0,
                    min: 0.0,
                    max: 9.9,
                    step: 0.1,
                    slide: function(event,ui){
                        $(".specialSearch form div b").val(ui.value);
                    }
                });
                $(".specialSearch form div b").val($("#juiSlideIMDB").slider("value"));
            });
        </script>
        <div>IMDB Vote: <b></b></div>
        <div id="juiSlideIMDB"></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

This code, **specialSearch form div b** value doesn't change. But, this line:

```
$(".specialSearch form div b").val($("#juiSlideIMDB").slider("value"));
```

to

```
$(".specialSearch form div b").text($("#juiSlideIMDB").slider("value"));
```

**val** -> **text** not in the current. So, changing once. It for the first value.

Slider tries values(**.specialSearch form div b**) ​​change.

How do we do?

Thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am solved. Thanks..

```
<div class="specialSearch">
    <form action="#" method="GET">
        <script type="text/javascript">
             $(function() {
                $( "#juiSlideIMDB" ).slider({
                    value: 7.0,
                    min: 0.1,
                    max: 9.9,
                    step: 0.1,
                    slide: function(event,ui){
                        $("#imdbVote").val(ui.value);
                    }
                });
                $("#imdbVote").val($("#juiSlideIMDB").slider("value"));
            });
        </script>
        <div>IMDB Vote: <input readonly="readonly" type="text" id="imdbVote" /></div>
        <div id="juiSlideIMDB"></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

## imdbVote css;

```
#imdbVote{position:absolute;border:0;color:#f6931f;font-weight:bolder;width:25px;}
```